# Purpose of an inductor in an automotive brake light switch

Tags: switches, inductor, automotive

I recently opened a brake light switch I replaced in my car. Here is a quick schematic I drew up of the switch design and the way it's wired:

[image: Circuit schematic]

V is the switched 12V supply feed. SW1 is normally open, and connects when the pedal is pressed. SW2 is normally closed, and disconnects when the pedal is pressed. The wiring harness of the car sits between the switch and the lamps, at the short link in this schematic.

The value of C1 is 4.7uF, 50V as labeled. I have estimated the L1 inductance using the equation \$L=\frac{N^2A\mu_0\mu_r}{l}\$:
\$L=\frac{17^2\cdot\left(\pi\cdot\left(2.5\text{mm}\right)^2\right)\cdot4\pi\cdot10^{-7}\text{(Vs)}\text{(Am)}^{-1}\cdot3500}{2\text{cm}}=1.25\text{mH}\$

I am not sure what the relative permeability of a ferrite core is, and got 3500 from a cursory online search. See the below photo of the inductor.

[image: Photo of inductor]

What is the purpose of the inductor L1 in the switch? My own knowledge suggests to me that this inductor will induce high voltage and arcing on the switch contacts as they disconnect, especially because of the large current flow due to the incandescent brake lamps.

However, I'm sure that the GM engineers designing this switch added it for a reason that I'm not seeing. What could that be?

Comment: 3.5 mH sounds like a grossly high estimation. Post a picture of the inductor.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added a photo to the question, and the equation for the estimation I made. I double checked it and got 1.25mH rather than 3.5mH.

Comment: FYI, mu_eff of a rod core of that aspect ratio is probably around 40. "Effective" because, while the ferrite might be 2000 or so, it's not making a full closed magnetic loop, rather it's surrounded by air.  The magnetic path is a mix of air and ferrite, which reduces the average/apparent/effective mu_r.

Answer (score 1):

All I can give you is an observation about the circuit and what the likely reason for L1 being present is.

Without L1, when the SW1 closes, it shorts out C1 (a charged capacitor). That can produce a current surge of hundreds of amps. With L1 present, the current surge might be tens of amps and not damage SW1.

Your calculation for the inductance value is slightly flawed. the distance \$\ell\$ in the formula is the circular distance of the path that the average/effective magnetic flux takes. For an open-ended inductor (a massive air-gap) the path will be at least twice the length of the ferrite core.

But, of more significance is the effective permeability of the path the flux takes; sure it passes through a core of length 20 mm but, for the remainder of the magnetic circuit, it passes through air. Air is dominant here and dominates the effective permeability by a mile. You should use a relative permeability of unity and not 3500 because of the massive dominance of the air-gap.

Comment: Thank you for the info - though it still confuses me why in particular to use a small inductor over, say, a small resistor of 1-2 Ohm in series with the capacitor which should surely achieve the same thing.

Comment: @M.Bromilow if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't yet have the reputation to upvote the answer. I would mark it accepted, though perhaps I should have written my question differently: e.g. *why* would this solution be chosen over something more standard like an R-C snubber. (I don't know the SE etiquette for this -- do I add it into the question despite it "moving the goalposts", or accept the answer since it answers the written question?)

Comment: @M.Bromilow nobody likes goalpost changes. The use of a resistor will reduce the light intensity and it will get a little warm and, it might not be regarded as robust as the inductor you showed.